Screen tearing in a specific horizontal line on the screen -- fixed by resizing screen -- Ubuntu 24.04
Screen tearing appears in a specific, horizontal line about two-thirds down the screen (see photo below).
The problem goes away if I change the resolution from 4K to 2K and back to 4K, so whatever happens during the resolution change seems to have a positive effect. However, the screen tearing appears again after restarting the system.
I have attached a photo taken by my phone, since I was unable to capture a video or screenshot using built-in software.

I'm on a completely fresh install on Ubuntu 24.04.1
Nvidia proprietary driver 550
Nvidia RTX 4070
Asus PB287Q monitor at 4k (3840*2160) resolution.



I found a solution. It turns out that just having any Xorg.conf file saved from Nvidia settings worked. Here are the steps to reproduce my solution:

Run sudo chmod +x /usr/share/screen-resolution-extra/nvidia-polkit

This is necessary so nvidia settings can actually save the xorg file. You might not need this, but for me, nvidia setting was unable to save the xorg file before I did this.


Run nvidia settings either by searching for it in the app list or typing nvidia-settings in the command-line
Chose the "X Server Display Configuration" tab.
Without changing any settings, click "Save to X configuration"

The default location /etc/X11/xorg.conf seems to be fine
Some solutions online mention the advanced setting "Force full composition pipeline", but it was not necessary to enable it in my case.



The screen tearing is now gone, although I don't quite understand why this worked.
